# .NET 6 API POD exiting with code 0 in AKS

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks

I have a .net core api project for which I have added docker support. The application runs fine in local but when I deploy it in AKS cluster the container immediately stops without printing any log. While running in local I have to supply the docker run -it command to run it, how I could run this AKS, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please share your deployment file and look at the pod status by doing `kubectl get pods`. Provide more information in order to reproduce your issue: screenshots would be useful too.

Comment: See the article from a official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/aks-hci/deploy-windows-application